# Which terms are used in context to mathematical proofs?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, education

There are many specific terms that are mostly only used in mathematical papers, e.g. Axiom, Lemma, Postulate, Definition (I know that it is used quite frequently in other domains), Proposition, Theorem.

Are there more terms that I am not aware of?

(Terms that are used specifically in context to proofs in a mathematical paper)

Comment: All of these are ubiquitous in other domains, too.

Comment: Are there more terms that you are not aware of? Certainly yes. I even believe that there are more terms that I am not aware of. But I'm not going to guess what you are and are not aware of.